# getElementsByTagName doesn't apply to every tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the color of every h1 in my page but it doesn't change to anything with this code:

```js
function toggleDark() {
  document.body.style.background = "#1e1e1e";
  document.body.style.color = "#fff";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1").style.color = "#fff";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleDark()">DM</a>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>WLJ</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>BB</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

However when I click I add an [0], it works but only with the first h1...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.color = "#fff";
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code, what I want is to get every h1 in white when clicking on the

Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")` returns an array, you have to loop through it.

Comment: You might want to use CSS classes for that instead. Add a class to the body and add a rule in CSS like : `body.yourClass h1{color: #fff; ...}`

Comment: You need to itrate through array of element and apply the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my contribution.

As [Mamun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7461381/mamun) stated, `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

You can iterate it and then set the colour to individual elements:

---

```js
function toggleDark() {
  document.body.style.background = "#1e1e1e";
  
  let headers = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].style.color = "#fff";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleDark()">DM</a>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>WLJ</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>BB</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns *HTMLCollection*. You have to loop through all the element to set the style individually:

```js
function toggleDark() {
  document.body.style.background = "#1e1e1e";
  document.body.style.color = "#fff";
  [...document.getElementsByTagName("h1")].forEach(function(h){
    h.style.color = "#fff";
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="toggleDark()">DM</a>
<section>
   <div class="container">
      <h1>WLJ</h1>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h1>BB</h1>
   </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: I really don't think this solution is suitable for his issue. using CSS classes would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Zenoo, OP is trying this in JS.

Comment: It doesn't mean we can't show him a better way, come on ^^

Comment: @Zenoo ask OP first if you want him to do that. Also **Mamun**, try use that code in Fiddle, it won't let you use `.forEach`